# Are pricing advice questions ok?

Tags: discussion

[Wedding Photography Pricing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48962/wedding-photography-pricing) is asking for advice that is specific to a location, currency and time.

Any accurate advice is going to be very specific to local market conditions and is going to be out of date reasonably quickly.

Should it be closed?

Answer (score 6):

No, the question can be edited to ask general guidelines to pricing. Though I feel I've seen such a question before.